# Lightning Styling not working on VisualForce Page

Tags: visualforce, lightning-experience, css, slds

I have a complex VF page that needs a lot of updates, so I've created a copy of it to work on.
Apart from the name, all else is identical - it even (for now) points to the same controller.
In Setup, in Visualforce Pages, I've tries setting the 'Available for Lightning Experience, Lightning Communities, and the mobile app' checkbox, even though the original did not have this set.

But, on the original page, the Lightning Styling works, while on my copy it doesn't. 2 screenshots - the first is what it's supposed to look like, the second is what the new page looks like.

[image: Original, Working page]

[image: New, non-working page]

If I look in Dev tools, I can see a CSS difference:

The original page uses:

https://britisheventing--prodmirror--c.cs110.visual.force.com/apexpages/slds/latest/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-vf.min.css

The new page uses:
https://britisheventing--prodmirror--c.cs110.visual.force.com/slds/css/lKu4b4zrMH3Fa5dSdO_jjA/min/scoped/one:oneNamespace,force:sldsTokens,force:base,force:oneSalesforceSkin,force:levelTwoDensity,force:themeTokens,force:formFactorLarge/slds.css

So, both style sheets come from the same Org, but different paths, and have different names.

The first 3 lines of both pages read:

```
 <apex:page standardStylesheets="false" applyHtmlTag="true" applyBodyTag="true" docType="html-5.0"  tabStyle="Entry__c" controller="RefundEntriesCtrl">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <apex:slds />
```

Edit:

I added:

```
{!URLFOR($Asset.SLDS, '/')}
```

to both pages.
On the page that works, it displayed:

```
/apexpages/slds/latest/
```

On the page that doesn't, it displayed:

```
/_slds/
```

This makes no sense, but is happening. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found the cause! The original VF Page used SF Api version 40 and the new one, version 47. 
I changed the new page to Api version 40, and now it looks the same.

Now all I have to do now is figure out how to make it look the same with Api 47 - I don't want it stuck with an Api from 2017!

Comment: Have the same, change from v41 to v42 breaks it